# MySQL C API memory leak?

Tags: mysql, c, api, memory-leaks, valgrind

Recently, I started to work on a C program that makes use of the `libmysqlclient`. When checking my code with `valgrind`, it reported memory leaks. The following minimal code snippet reproduces the behavior:

```
#include <mysql.h>

int main(void)
{
    MYSQL* mysql = mysql_init(0);

    mysql_close(mysql);

    return 0;
}
```

Checking the resulting program with `valgrind` tells me:

```
==25614== LEAK SUMMARY:
==25614==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25614==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25614==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25614==    still reachable: 288 bytes in 3 blocks
==25614==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

According to the MySQL API Reference, `mysql_close()`...

> Closes a previously opened connection. mysql_close() also deallocates the connection handle pointed to by mysql if the handle was allocated automatically by mysql_init() or mysql_connect().

However, `valgrind` reports un-freed memory. What's wrong here?

Comment: Maybe internal buffers that are initialized once?

Comment: I think this is related to a valgrind detecting leak from using localtime and friends

Comment: Michael: You're right, see my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Digging through the docs, I found the function `mysql_library_end()` that solves the issue.

Citing from the MySQL API Reference:

> This function finalizes the MySQL library. You should call it when you are done using the library (for example, after disconnecting from the server).

On a personal note, I find it rather annoying that `libmysqlclient` forces its users to call its own cleanup function. IMO, a nicer solution would be to call `mysql_library_end()` automatically whenever the connection count drops to zero.

Comment: 6 minutes can make a difference

Comment: Ulterior: wording the question took me longer  :|

Comment: I noticed the same today and found it a bit silly that one has to manually call the library_end o.O